# Getting JSON data out of a POST body in Spark + Kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin

I'm playing around with Kotlin and Spark, creating a RESTful web service. However I'm struggling to parse a JSON POST request. I have the following endpoint...

```
    post("") { req, res ->
        var objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        println(req.body())
        val data = objectMapper.readValue(req.body(), User::class.java)
        usersDao.save(data.name, data.email, data.age)
        res.status(201)
        "okies"
    }
```

However I'm getting a 500 error, it's not actually printing an error, just returning a 500.

It seems to be this line `val data = objectMapper.readValue(req.body(), User::class.java)`. I'm attempting to convert the json body into a user object. Here's my user object...

```
data class User(val name: String, val email: String, val age: Int, val id: Int)
```